# Why general elements of ideal are non-zero divisors?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, cohen-macaulay

I'm readind the article: A formula for the core of an ideal, by Bernd Ulrich and Claudia Polini and I'm having trouble each time the doubt involves the concept of general element of an ideal

Well, this isn't a concept widely known at the Commutative Algebra literature. The definition that was passed me is

> Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. We say $x \in I$ is general element if $x$ is in non-empty Zariski open of $I/(\mathfrak{m}I)$.

The problem is that this definition seems complicated to manipulate and generate useful results. For example, at Lemma 4.2, the author says:

> Let $R$ be Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $I$ be an ideal de $R$. If $ht(I)>0$ and $x \in I$ is general element, then $x$ is $R$-regular element.

Can someone help me at last resul I mentioned? Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you know that in a commutative Noetherian  ring, the set of zero divisors is just the union of all associated primes? Do you know that in a CM ring, all associated primes are minimal? Do you know that if an ideal $I$ is contained in a finite union of prime ideals, then it is contained in one of the prime ideals?

Comment: When the definition says that x belongs to non-empty zariski open set, is it mean that x belongs to some prime that is in complement of some closed set of I/\mathfrak{m}I with induced topology of R/(mathafrak{m}I)? Or don't x belongs to set of zeros of finite family polynomials with coeficients in I/mathfrak{m}I?

Comment: The argument works only if the residue filed is infinite. From what I said earlier, it follows that for any minimal prime $P$, the image of $P\cap I\to I/\mathfrak{m}I$ is a proper subspace. Doing this for the finitely many minimal primes, the union of these proper subspaces form a proper Zariski closed set. Pick any $x\in I$ whose image is in the open set complement to this closed set.

Comment: Yes, the residue field is infinity. I understood. Thanks